# Laravel intervention/image resize is returning null. Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I can't figure it out.  When I resize the uploaded image like so,

```
public function up(Request $request) {

    $user = $request->user();
    $image= $request->file('images');
        if(!empty(($image))){
        $files = Input::file('images');
        foreach($files as $file) {
            if(!empty($file)){
    $new_file = Image::make($file)->resize(200,200);
    var_dump($new_file);exit;
```

var_dump returns this:

```
object(Intervention\Image\Image)#241 (9) {
object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Driver)#242 (2) {
["decoder"] object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Decoder)#243 (1) {
}
["encoder"] object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Encoder)#244 (4) {
["result"] NULL
["image"] NULL
["format"] NULL
["quality"] NULL
}
}
object(Imagick)#237 (0) {
}
["backups":protected] array(0) {
}
["encoded"] ""
["mime"] "image/jpeg"
["dirname"] "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php"
["basename"] "phpJcAyxV"
["extension"] NULL
["filename"] "phpJcAyxV"
}
```

result, image,format,quality is all null.  What am I missing here?

**UPDATE** this is the HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>'FileController@up','files'=>true,))!!}
<div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-2'>
        {!! Form::label('images','Profile Picture')!!}
        </div>
    <div class='col-md-2 profile-pic'>
      @if(isset($pic)) 
      <img src='{{$pic}}'/>
      @else 
      <img src='/images/user-icon.jpg'/>
      @endif
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        {!! Form::file('images[]') !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('category','profile')!!}
        {!! Form::submit('Upload',['class'=>'form-control btn btn-md btn-info','style'=>'width:100px; margin-top:50px;'])!!}
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Maybe I shouldn't use an array?

Comment: Are you passing in multiple files? Can you post your HTML as well? Because I can see a few things you could fix, but it depends on what you sending to the server.

Comment: I'm only passing in one file, but I use an array anyway.  I have another form that actually uploads more than 1 file at a time, so I would like to know how to resize them as array objects

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I took a closer look at your question. The encoder values are null because you just haven't set them. I'm assuming you weren't planning on encoding them. You **still** do have an image. Your server successfully received it. It just means you didn't encode it.

Also, in this code:

```
public function up(Request $request) {

    $user = $request->user();
    $image= $request->file('images');

    if(!empty(($image))) {
        $files = Input::file('images');
```

You don't need to use the `Input` facade to grab the images because you already got all the images when you did `$request->file('images');`.

In other words, `Input::file('images')` is exactly the same thing as `$request->file('images')`.

Also, instead of checking whether or not it's empty, I think it's a little more readable to use the `hasFile` method, so I think something like this is more readable:

```
public function up(Request $request) {

    $user = $request->user();

    if($request->hasFile('images')) {

        $files = $request->file('images');
```

Overall, it would just be:

```
public function up(Request $request) {

    $user = $request->user();

    if($request->hasFile('images')) {

        $files = $request->file('images');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $new_file = Image::make($file)->resize(200,200);
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, when you `dd($new_file)` the encoder properties will still be false, but you still have an image. For example, if you `return $new_file->response();`, you should see the image in the new size that you set.

If you do want to encode your image, the Intervention Image package provides an `encode` method.

```
$new_file = Image::make($file)->resize(200,200)->encode();
```

Answer (score 0):

By some reason, this work for me:

I have a current image in the filesystem, I was rotating but nothing happens, I check in source from google dev options and saw the same error you got.

```
object(Intervention\Image\Image)#716 (9) {
  ["driver":protected]=>
  object(Intervention\Image\Gd\Driver)#718 (2) {
    ["decoder"]=>
    object(Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder)#719 (1) {
      ["data":"Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder":private]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["encoder"]=>
    object(Intervention\Image\Gd\Encoder)#720 (4) {
      ["result"]=>
      NULL
      ["image"]=>
      NULL
      ["format"]=>
      NULL
      ["quality"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
```

In the controller:

```
public function rotatePhoto($id)
{
        $photo = BookPublicationPhoto::find($id);
        $image_url = storage_path().'/cache/img/publication/'.$photo->published_book_id.'/'.$photo->image_file_name;
        $img = Image::make($image_url);
        // rotate image 90 degrees clockwise
        $img->rotate(-45);
        var_dump($img);
        $response['mensaje'] = "No tienes los permisos para eliminar ésta foto";
}
```

And the **solution** is add `$img->save();` after the `$img->rotate(-45);` the action(rotate, resize..)

**[DOCS](http://image.intervention.io/api/save)**